# How to replace part of a line with sed

Tags: sed, grep

I want to replace the part of a line that *doesn't match*. For example I have a line from grep:

`./XYZ/SportsDataManager.m:static NSString* REDEEM_SPORT_CREDIT_URL    = @"http://example.com/clients/XYZ/services/sports/prod/prod_sportRedeemUserCredit.php";`

From what I've read, it's best to pipe this through sed. I want to remove everything EXCEPT the url. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I would use egrep with -o, for example

```
 echo "./XYZ/SportsDataManager.m:static NSString* REDEEM_SPORT_CREDIT_URL = @\"http://example.com/clients/XYZ/services/sports/prod/prod_sportRedeemUserCredit.php\";" | egrep 'http://.*?\.php' -o
http://example.com/clients/XYZ/services/sports/prod/prod_sportRedeemUserCredit.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed, if you always have URLs within double quotes:

```
sed -n 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' input
```